# Ejecutar Una Acción Durante Un Tiempo Transcurrido

Tags: c#

Intento ejecutar cada 5 minutos de tiempo de ejecución para una orden con C# en mi aplicación lo mas deseable es de intentar `No poner en modo de espera la aplicación` para así no ralentizar su uso me pregunto como se podría lograr esto

Comment: Como intentas ejecutar la accion cada 5 minutos?

Comment: Mm.. todavía no puedo lograrlo

Comment: Busca un poco sobre `System.Threading`, como crear un cronometro en otro thread y cómo ejecutar una acción cada cierto tiempo, construye tu codigo y si tienes problemas, avisanos!

Comment: Lo mejor para esto es que simplemente utilices una Tarea Programada de Windows. Te evita tener que escribir código y funciona perfectamente

Comment: Puedes usar [Quartz Enterprise Scheduler .NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) para crear las tareas programadas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrastra un timer a tu proyecto

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLqRz.jpg]

En las propiedades de intervalo le pones 300000 ya que se mide en milisegundos y es el equivalente a 5 minutos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En eventos hace doble click en Tick

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto te va a generar en el código, donde dentro de ese evento pones lo que queres que pase cada cinco minutos

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString ("Prueba"));
}
```

Lo único que te falta es habilitar el timer que lo podes hacer cuando arranca la aplicación modificando la propiedad Enabled a true, si queres que arranque cuando el usuario haga una determinada accion solo debes utilizar

```
timer1.Start();
```

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Si tu aplicación es de consola o queres hacer todo mediante código vas a tener que hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Creamos el timer y le seteamos el intervalo
            System.Timers.Timer oTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            oTimer.Interval = 5000;

            oTimer.Elapsed += EventoIntervalo;

            oTimer.Enabled = true;

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void EventoIntervalo(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Evento convocado a las: {0}", e.SignalTime);
        }
    }
```

En este caso cada 5 segundos va a entrar al evento y te va a mostrar la fecha y hora actual, en tu caso que queres que el evento se realice cada 5 minutos vas a tener que cambiar **oTimer.Interval = 5000;** a **oTimer.Interval = 300000;** e insertar tu código de ejecución en EventoIntervalo

Comment: Estoy Muy agradecido de respuestas que me has proporcionado Muchas gracias !